# Get path to libs from binary

Tags: node.js

In my `package.json` I have `"bin":{...}` specified. The binary is shebang node script `#!/usr/bin/env node`. Node will install binary into the separate directory (`/usr/local/bin` in my case), now from this binary I want to require the `lib.js` file that is located in lib/ dir, but Node will install the libraries in separate dir somewhere else (in my case on Ubuntu it is `/usr/var/lib/node_modules/my_module`). Now how do I require it?